# Design pattern for parser

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a program which requests web page, parses it and depends on result decides what to do next.

For example: Program should obtain some element from page, let's call it "aim element". If program does request and obtains "someOtherElement" it will continue execution. If it obtains "aimElement" Executor should click some links, execution ends and we go to the next task. Program has 20 attempts to obtain "aimElement". And "aimElement" could change in the future.

Seems simple but I don't really know how to implement this with good oo-design. I am thinking of two objects: Task and Executor. Task contains all conditions and Executor receives Task as an argument and does requests based on Task's needs. But if executor returns raw page to Task itself Task will be to complicated and there will be strong connection between them. If Executor returns already parsed elements of a page then Executor will need to know what and how to parse and will be also complicated and also there will be strong connection.

I don't know if my explanation clear or not but maybe you could advice me some design pattern or just share your experience with similar problems.

Comment: Yust to make sure - you want to parse an HTML document and find certain nodes?

Comment: XML contents HTML. In the XML I search for node with my element if I find it I'll find node with HTML and parse links which I should click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a push parser and allow Tasks to register themselves for whatever events they are interested in. Basically your parser parses the document once and informs all subscribers about the kind of things they are interested in (say "img with URL X" or "link to Y").

You can then either query the subscribers to see what to do next (at the end/after every event), or let them inform you with a listener approach yourself.

The best part is that I'm sure there's already a push parser for HTML in Java, so you avoid quite some work.

Comment: +1 This sounds like what you'll want to do Moses. You could use something as simple as a SAX parser (built-in to Java). If you really need to implement the full stack of the parser, you might be interested in something like the [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Comment: But if "aimElement" changes I will have to write new Task class and make changes to Executor. Is there an aproach where I will be able not to touch bouth classes?

Comment: @Moses Why would you have to touch the executor? Easiest approach: 1. All your tasks register for the events they're interested in. 2. Parse document. 3. Query your tasks to decide what to do next (that could be as simple as a "give me all the URLs I should visit next" method; if that set is empty you're finished) - this can be extracted in its own class too if you may need to change that later.

Comment: About SAX: SAX is a great XML parser, but sadly lots of HTML on the net isn't wellformed XML which will cause it to fail, so you need the additional knowledge about your sources. If you can use SAX it's probably the best you can get.